# How do I know which version of Minecraft I have?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I don't know which version of Minecraft I have. I have regular Minecraft, not Java or anything else and I just don't know the version I have.

Comment: ExpertCoder, i did try to find how to know which version of minecraft i have, but i couldn't find anything for bedrock. Even the pictures wouldn't tell me anything and the videos were just for java edition.

Comment: Which device are you on? Computer, phone, console, etc?

Comment: I am on a p.c. :)

Comment: Which of the two menu screens is closest to what yours looks like? And does the title say "Minecraft: Java Edition" or "Minecraft"?

Comment: Minecraft and only minecraft. I have version 1.14.60. I checked minecraft and saw it thanks to everyone's help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply look at the bottom of Minecraft's title screen.

At the bottom right or bottom left, you should see a number. (1.14.4, 1.13, etc.)

If the number is in the bottom left, you are using Java Edition, also evident in the subtitle below the main title.
[image]

If the number is in the bottom right, you are using Bedrock Edition. This is evident because Bedrock Edition just uses the title *Minecraft* with no subtitle.
[image: Bedrock Edition Title Screen]
The number itself is the version number.

Comment: thats helpful, i have 1.14.60

Answer (score 4):

It should be pretty simple:

In Java edition your Minecraft version will be shown in the lower left hand corner of your screen.

[image]

This is Java edition, but is essentially the same for Bedrock edition except it should be on the other side corner like this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check if your version has an "Achievements" menu for Bedrock, or an "Advancements" menu for Java.