# Minecraft fully-auto fuel source?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

(I believe) I’m using the latest version of Minecraft Bedrock Edition (1.17.10) and I want to know if I can design a fully-auto fuel system for furnaces/smokers/blast furnaces?

Things I’ve thought about:

> I’ve wondered about kelp, but you have to craft dried kelp into kelp blocks to use it as fuel, so I don’t think this is possible

> Maybe bamboo would work? The only thing with bamboo is that it doesn’t last long as fuel, so I’d probably need massive amounts of it to keep smokers going.

> How about lava with drip stones to fill cauldrons so I can use lava buckets? I don’t know how to get something to fill a bucket with lava, place it into a smoker for fuel, come out afterwards, and grab more lava!

**Question:** Can someone give a link or an idea of how to make a ***FULLY***-auto fuel source to keep at least 1 smoker going all day? If needed, I can scale up from whatever you all come up with.

As always, thanks!

Comment: [This post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370607/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-minecraft-i-have#:~:text=Simply%20look%20at%20the%20bottom%20of%20Minecraft%27s%20title,the%20bottom%20right%2C%20you%20are%20using%20Bedrock%20Edition.) explains how to check your version number for Bedrock, in case you'd like to confirm it.

Comment: @taco I know what it is, just not if it’s the latest version (but I’m pretty darn sure it is)

Comment: Ah, yes, it is the latest version. The next version (*1.17.20*) is still listed as upcoming on the [fandom](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Bedrock_Edition_version_history#:~:text=%20%20%20%20Version%20%20%20,March%209%2C%202021%20%2010%20more%20rows%20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this universal wood farm design by SilentWhisperer, and then hooking it up with hoppers to a super smelter to create charcoal (Also designed by SilentWhisperer). Once you create that charcoal, you can then hook that up to whatever furnace you want to smelt automatically. Just note that the wood farm needs to use bone meal. I recommend finding a bonemeal video by SilentWhisperer or JCPlayz, because they mostly specialist in making Minecraft Bedrock Edition farms.

Wood Farm:
[Silentwhisperer's Wood Farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IruU7L-GEec)

Super Smelter:
[Silentwhisperer's Super Smelter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzGvsIH8tAY)

Comment: It seems like both links are the same?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I'll edit that right now...

Comment: Fixed it! It should work rn.

Comment: Can you please break down some of the content within those videos, just-in-case they are ever taken down? This will ensure that future readers gain the ability to achieve the same result even if the videos are removed.

Comment: Ok, but the videos are very technical, so i'll do my best to provide a summary of them.

Answer (score 0):

Build a large scale bamboo farm with flyign machines and as long as those chuncks are rendered, itll be fully automatic, you can try building a redstone chunk loader.(pretty sure ilmango has a video on them)

Comment: How do I get it picked up and into a furnace? I can’t seem to get a smoker going because the minecart hopper isn’t fast enough at collecting and loading... it usually loads 2 as it goes by. How do I get it to stay for longer and then collect again to keep smokers going?

Comment: use multiple hopper minecarts ona  track, make a big bamboo farm, you can check out mumbo jummo's design from hermitcraft season 7

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! Please elaborate on your answer to give clarity to those who do not know how to perform the individual sub-tasks, otherwise, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Add a platform 2 blocks below the ground of the farm, make multiple tracks, one next to another, put minecart with hopper on the track and at one end have hoppers to take the items from the minecarts. Have the minecarts always going and make a redstone chunk loader which i personally dont know how to build.