# Unbreaking Golden Pickaxe Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an Unbreaking Golden Pickaxe in Minecraft that only breaks Light Blue Concrete. What command would I need to use?

Comment: What edition of Minecraft are you playing? Please add the corresponding tag.

Comment: im playin in 1.17.11

Comment: Is this Java or Bedrock edition?

Comment: Java i think idk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An item to break only SPECIFIED blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246297/an-item-to-break-only-specified-blocks) and [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/191554/185203)

Comment: ii tried it there but it won't work

Comment: i know the command but it wont work when i only want a Pickaxe that only Breaks Light Blue Concrete

Comment: "*Java I think idk*", if the version number is in the bottom left of your menu, it's Java edition; if it's in the bottom right, it's Bedrock edition. See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370607/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-minecraft-i-have) for more information on determining your edition.